# getting error while deploying war to JBOSS using gradle cargo plugin

Tags: deployment, gradle, jboss, war

## build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE"
      classpath "org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.6"
    }
  }

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "cargo"

group = "myorg"
version = 1.0

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.all { set ->
    def jarTask = task("${set.name}Jar", type: Jar) {
        baseName = baseName + "-$set.name"
        from set.output
    }

    artifacts {
        archives jarTask
    }
}

sourceSets {
    api
    impl
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
      mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
  }

dependencies {
    apiCompile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.1.4'
    implCompile sourceSets.api.output
    implCompile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.9'
    testCompile sourceSets.api.output
    testCompile sourceSets.impl.output
    runtime configurations.apiRuntime
    runtime configurations.implRuntime
}

jar {
    from sourceSets.api.output
    from sourceSets.impl.output
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri("${buildDir}/repo"))

            addFilter("main") { artifact, file -> artifact.name == project.name }
            ["api", "impl"].each { type ->
                addFilter(type) { artifact, file -> artifact.name.endsWith("-$type") }

                // We now have to map our configurations to the correct maven scope for each pom
                ["compile", "runtime"].each { scope ->
                    configuration = configurations[type + scope.capitalize()]
                    ["main", type].each { pomName ->
                        pom(pomName).scopeMappings.addMapping 1, configuration, scope
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'jboss42x'
    port = 8080
    remote {
        hostname = 'localhost'
    }
}
```

===================================

Above is my Gradle code

what is missing? I want to deploy war to 
C:\developmentapps\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy

I am getting following error after I added code for cargo ...

=================================================

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      build
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\*\server\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'server'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'cargo']
   > java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.466 secs
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:117)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.launch.GradleProcess$1.doit(GradleProcess.java:92)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\Users\ea8b26s\Dropbox\server\build.gradle' line: 17
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'server'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:134)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:258)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleCancel.execute(HandleCancel.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:154)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'server'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:190)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:521)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'cargo']
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_spds5rkapu3dfnubh8iqgg6dq.run(C:\Users\ea8b26s\Dropbox\server\build.gradle:17)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration
    at org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration$Namer.determineName(Configuration.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:70)
    at java_util_Set$add.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.cargo.CargoPlugin.apply(CargoPlugin.groovy:39)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.cargo.CargoPlugin.apply(CargoPlugin.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:188)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:115)
    ... 66 more
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 1 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the buildscript dependency from

```
classpath "org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.6"
```

to the newer one

```
classpath("org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.6.1")
```

It hepled me to make it running with Gradle 2.6. Don't know why, but it seems to be, that the Gradle and Cargo plugin versions are not compatible with each other.